# Symfony roles - how to design?

Tags: symfony, roles

I am trying to achieve some scenario using Voters but I am not sure if that's a good approach, so let me explain.

My application is split into `frontoffice` and `backoffice`. Front Office is mainly client area while Back Office for management team.

So I was thinking to make two main roles in `access_control` (something like that):

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/.+/backoffice, roles: [ROLE_BACKOFFICE] }
    - { path: ^/.+/frontoffice, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_FRONTOFFICE] }
```

Based on those roles we can determine who should be able to access the given links.

And now, if you access `backoffice`, I must be able to determine which section user should see and what permissions he has on that section.

Example 1:

`ROLE`: `ROLE_MANAGER`

`SECTION`: `SECTION_CLIENTS, SECTION_REPORTS, SECTION_PROGRAMS, SECTION_SCHEDULE`

`PERMISSION`: `CAN_VIEW, CAN_CREATE, CAN_EDIT, CAN_DELETE`

Example 2:

`ROLE`: `ROLE_INTERN`

`SECTION`: `SECTION_REPORTS`

`PERMISSION`: `CAN_VIEW`

All the roles should be managable through interface and storable in the database.

I tried to use Voters for that but I was trying to use it like this:

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('view', 'SECTION_REPORTS' 'Unauthorized access!');
```

But this was complaining that 2nd parameter must be an object, well Reports is just a view so I cannot pass string, I could create a simple object for that I guess, and pass it like this:

```
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('view', new SectionReport(), 'Unauthorized access!');
```

and do all the necessary logic in the ReportsVoter class but then how I am going to either show or hide menus in Twig by using

```
    {% if is_granted('view', 'SECTION_REPORTS') %}
        <p>ACCESS GRNANTED</p>
    {% endif %}
```

Shall I just create a custom TwigExtension with my own is_granted method?
Or the idea is completely wrong and I should make it differently?

I know that FOSUserBundle exists but I am not going to use it, since it contains too much configuration, unwanted.

One more thing, the configuration panel will look similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Writing your own twig extension would work.  But I'm guessing that as you get further into you design then you may find that having section objects might end up being useful.  Take a look at any duplicate code you might be writing between sections and see if it makes sense to add it to a section class.